# How to find element with dynamic names in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My code:

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Label"
       class="other[] form-control"
       name="projectsurvey[1438590696705][choosekey][1438590696705][]" 
       value="">
```

Where `name projectsurvey[changes][choosekey][changes]`

I'm using this to try to find the item: `xpath("//*[starts-with(@name,'projectsurvey','choosekey')])`

The firebug xpath is showing like this :

```
*[@id="choice1438590696705"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/input
```

and the firebug xpath changes:

```
[@id="choice143......."]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/input
```

How do I find this element by xpath

Is there any other way to find this element

Comment: Can you paste some more html content

Comment: Everything in name="" is getting changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'contains' :

```
//input[contains(@name, 'projectsurvey[143') and contains(@name, 'choosekey][143')]
```

Comment: @saiviswanath - if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, then delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had more complicated situation, even 'contains' was not enough. I got list of all elements of type (find by TAG_NAME), then looped over the list to find elements of interest by parts of id and class name. I had even to find matching pairs of  elements with parts of name generated dynamically.

Because of flexible list processing in Python, it was not too hard. I try to avoid XPATH: real programming language like Python, which I already know, gives me more flexibility and is easier to maintain, than cryptic and obscure XPATH expressions. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many more similar elements you have on the page, an xpath like the following may do what you need:

```
//input[@type='text'][contains(@class,'form-control')][contains(@name,'projectsurvey')]
```